# How to know if a tag has been added within a taxonomy?

Tags: forms, customization, reset

I have a custom form field within a taxonomy. However when a new term/tag has been added I need to clear some values through javascript. How can I do this?

I found the following code snippet in WordPress:

```
a.post(ajaxurl,a("#addtag").serialize(),function(h)
{
    a("#ajax-response").empty();

    var f=wpAjax.parseAjaxResponse(h,"ajax-response");

    if(!f||f.errors){return}

var g=b.find("select#parent").val();

if(g>0&&a("#tag-"+g).length>0){
    a(".tags #tag-"+g).after(f.responses[0].supplemental.noparents)}
else
    {a(".tags").prepend(f.responses[0].supplemental.parents)}

a(".tags .no-items").remove();

if(b.find("select#parent")){

var e=f.responses[1].supplemental;
var c="";

for(var d=0;d<f.responses[1].position;d++){c+="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"}

b.find("select#parent option:selected").after('<option value="'+e.term_id+'">'+c+e.name+"</option>")}

// = NOTE THE FOLLOWING LINE =============
a('input[type="text"]:visible, textarea:visible',b).val("")});
// =======================================

return false})});
```

It clears all the text input fields that are visible, however I have my own custom field that people can select an image and after the image has been selected a hidden input field value is changed with the selected image id and the image is shown through an image object.

However, after the user presses the 'Add new category' button I like to be able to reset the hidden input field and remove the image object.

I like to know when a category has been added so I can reset all that is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific on the "when a new term/tag has been added" part? Are you doing it yourself, as in you call the backend through admin-ajax.php and update the front-end accordingly? Including some code or a link to jsFiddle wouldn't hurt.

There's a [create_term action](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/create_term) you can hook into in the back-end. Just put this into functions.php or your plugin code:

```
function your_create_fn( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy ){
    // do your thing here
}
add_action( 'create_term', 'your_create_fn', 10, 3 );
```

Alternatively, if you're doing it yourself then you obviously control the entire process, so you know exactly when you've successfully added a new term and can return something to the JS function that indicates you need to clear those values.

Comment: I edited my question.